# What is this practice called? `objectName && objectName.thing`

Tags: javascript, terminology

I'm trying to find the name of the practice (in any language) in which one checks for an object to be in existence before performing a lookup on it. Usually this is done by throwing in an `&&` in between the object and the object lookup expression, like so in JS:

```
var example = objectName && objectName.thing;
```

such that `example` is evaluated to either `undefined` or `objectName.thing`, and avoids a runtime error.

I could have sworn I've heard this before, but I've completely forgotten. What is this practice called?

Comment: It's usually called a null check.

Comment: shorthand of **objectName ? objectName.thing : null**

Comment: @subash Not exactly identical, since `objectName` could be `undefined` or any other value as well.

Comment: check with logical AND and short circuit with falsy value?

Comment: @Xufox  undefined is also evaluate as false right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called a "guard," since the truthiness of the left operand *guards* access to the right operand. Of course, it's just a logical AND, but the use of AND in this specific context is occasionally called a "guard".

From Douglas Crockford's [A Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html):

> The `&&` operator is commonly called *logical and*. It can also be called *guard*.

From [Guard and Default Operators of JavaScript](http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators) by Sean McArthur:

> In Javascript, the way the languages determines logical operations and the values Javascript treats as true or false lead to people using the AND and OR operators for *guard* and *default* situations

Comment: Ah! The guard. Couldn't remember it for the life of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This practice is sometimes called validation, or evaluation. You can use a **ternary operator** to do so.

`var example = objectName ? objectName.thing : null`

This will assign `objectName.thing` or `null` to `example` depending on **objectExample**